# Use NVL with string in Django?

Tags: python, sql, django, oracle, nvl

On a Django app, I'm using cx_Oracle to display a roster of sports players:

```
def get_players(self, sport_code='', term=0):
"""

:rtype: object
"""
con = cx_Oracle.Connection(settings.BANNER_CONNECTION_URL)
cursor = con.cursor()
query = 'select PREF_NAME, CLASS, ELIGIBLE_HOURS, CHECKED_IN, SEASONS_USED, MAJR1, NVL(MINR1, Null), CA_EMAIL, ID from swvsprt_web where ACTC = \'%s\' AND term = \'%s\' ORDER BY PREF_NAME' % (
    sport_code, term)
cursor.execute(query)
players = cursor.fetchall()
cursor.close()
con.close()
return players
```

I want minor to just be blank if they don't have a minor

```
NVL(MINR1, Null)
```

But I can't quite get NVL to behave.  "Null" makes it print the word "None."  If I do

```
NVL(MINR1, 0)
```

it will display a 0, but if I try any of the following, they crash the site with a 500 error:

```
NVL(MINR1, )
```

`NVL(MINR1, '')`

`NVL(MINR1, "")`

Can we use NVL to make it show null values as just nothing?

Comment: where are you showing these values that you want them to appear blank instead of `None`? In html via a template?

Comment: Correct, the template is rendering a table by <td>{{ player.0 }}</td>, <td>{{ player.1 }}</td>, etc etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python, the 'null' object is the singleton `None`

If you want to display something else, you should post-process the data, and replace values of `None` in that field with an empty string.

A better alternative might be to just leave the values of `None` as is in your backend representation. This is more representative of not having a minor than an empty string.

Then, on your frontend template, you can check for a null value, and display an empty string if MINR1 is `None`.

Comment: Thank you.  So try handling it on the template layer instead of model layer.  I'm going to give this a shot.

Comment: @KevinCelebi did this work for you? If so, you can vote up/ accept my answer. Otherwise, I'm happy to help you continue to work through this.

Comment: I would love to upvote this but Stackoverflow won't let me do anything since I'm too new!  Thank you for the help though, the template layer is a lot more powerful than I knew.

Answer (score 0):

There's an analogy of Oracle's `NVL` in Django templates:

```
<td><span class="entityName">{{ attr.name|default_if_none:"" }}</span></td>
```

if `attr.name is None` an empty string will be output.

Here's the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#default-if-none).